# how can I set loggingLevel only for my program

Tags: python, logging

how can I set loggingLevel only for my program my code depends on some library and needs to set a logging level dynamically by passing in from args. the problem is if I use logging.basicConfig(level==logging.INFO), some library's log is also printed. Is there any way I can only print my own log? btw, my program has many files, setting log level for each logger is too much work